# Can `eshell-command` direct its output like `shell-command` into minibuffer?

Tags: eshell

=> When I do `M-x shell-command` and `python run.py` (which only print `Hello World\nHello World` string), I get the result on the minibuffer and when cursor moves up/down minibuffer is closed.

[image]

=> When I do `M-x eshell-command` and `pwd` I get the result on another window instead of the mini-buffer I had to do C-x-1 to close it. Please note that, if the output is single line it is printed in the minibuffer.

[image]

=> Can `eshell-command` direct its output like `shell-command` into minibuffer if the output is more than a single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't without modifying the code, but you can do it yourself

```
(defun your-eshell-command (command)
  "Execute eshell COMMAND and display output in the echo area."
  (interactive "sEshell command: ")
  (message "%s" (eshell-command-result command)))
```

`shell-command`'s output behavior is smarter

> If the output is short enough to
> display in the echo area (which is determined by the variables
> `resize-mini-windows` and `max-mini-window-height`), it is shown
> there

Comment: On native `eshell-command` tab works to do auto-completion, is it possible to achieve completion too in `your-eshell-command` func

Comment: It also prints additional new line at the end is it possible to prevent it from printing? which is not printed on `eshell-command`

Comment: @alper On completion, you need to copy-and-paste eshell-command's code, or use `read-shell-command` which is for shell not eshell, but might be good enough. On trailing new lines, you can use `string-trim-right` to remove them.

Comment: Ok as I understand, instead of `eshell-command-result` I can use `read-shell-command`

Comment: @alper nope, `(interactive "sEshell command: ")` is like `read-string` which does not provide completion, you use `(interactive (list (read-shell-command "Eshell command: ")))` to get completion.